# Finding a solution of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for a solution of the following differential equation:

$$ \frac{\lambda^{k+1} t^k}{(1+\lambda t)^k}=\frac{F'(t)}{1-F(t)}, $$ with $k = 1, 2, 3, \, \dots \, ,$ $ 0 < \lambda$ and $ 0 < t $.

Comment: This is a separable equation, and so can be solved by $\int\frac{\lambda^{k+1}t^k}{(1+\lambda t)^k}dt=\int\frac{1}{1-F}dF$

Comment: Would you perhaps like to elaborate it further or is there no solution for this differential equation?

Comment: This method has already been elaborated in PierreCarre answer

Comment: Let $u=1+\lambda t$. Then
$$\int \frac{\lambda^{k+1}t^k}{(1+\lambda t)^k}\,dt=
\int \big(1-u^{-1}\big)^k\,du=$$
$$\int \sum_{i=0}^k \binom ki(-1)^{i}u^{-i}\,du=$$
$$u-k\ln u+\sum_{i=2}^k \frac{(-1)^i}{1-i}\binom ki u^{1-i}+C=$$
$$1+\lambda t-k\ln(1+\lambda t)+\sum_{i=2}^k \frac{(-1)^i}{1-i}\binom ki(1+\lambda t)^{1-i}+C$$

Answer (score 1):

You can start by changing variables... Setting $G(t)= - \log(|1-F(t)|)$, the equation reduces (whenever $F(t)\ne 1$) to
$$
G'(t) = \frac{\lambda^{k+1} t^k}{(1+\lambda t)^k}
$$

Now it is just a matter of computing $G(t)$ by integration and rollback the variable change.

Comment: Firstly I perform:
$$ G(x) =  \int_0^x \, G'(t)  \,dx $$
I replace x with t in $G(x)$ and obtain $G(t)$.
Next I solve the equation $G(t)= - \log(|1-F(t)|)$ and obtain
$$ F(t) \, = \, 1-e^{-G(t)},1+e^{-G(t)}$$
I choose:
$$ F(t) \, = \, 1+e^{-G(t)}$$
Finally I define $f(t) = F'(t)$ and determine $h(t)$:
$$ h(t) = \frac{f(t)}{1-F(t)}$$
But then I do not obtain
$$ \frac{\lambda^{k+1} t^k}{(1+\lambda t)^k}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Integrating the RHS is no problem. On the LHS (WLOG $\lambda=1$)

$$\frac{t^k}{(t+1)^k}=\frac{(t+1-1)^k}{(t+1)^k}=\sum_{i=0}^k\binom ki(t+1)^{i-k}$$ can be integrated term by term.

Comment: I already knew that the differential equation could be solved term by term. But I am looking for a solution as a function of k.

Comment: @AdvanderVen: you won't find better than this. By the way, you should provide such information to avoid us wasting our time.

Comment: If you had told me from the beginning that there is no solution for this differential equation, it would have cost you and me less time.

Comment: I fully apologize. I really must not have understood it. I would appreciate it very much it if you would still give me the closed form of the solution. I am not a professional mathematician, although I have already published a number of articles in mathematical and semi-mathematical journals.

Comment: @AdvanderVen: you just integrate the powers $(t+1)^{n}\to(t+1)^{n+1}/(n+1)$, and $(1+t)^{-1}\to\ln(1+t)$. There is no further simplification, but this is a closed form.

Comment: Thanks a very lot. I am going to look into it. I will respond to you tomorrow.

Comment: Let $u=1+\lambda t$. Then
$$\int \frac{\lambda^{k+1}t^k}{(1+\lambda t)^k}\,dt=
\int \big(1-u^{-1}\big)^k\,du=$$
$$\int \sum_{i=0}^k \binom ki(-1)^{i}u^{-i}\,du=$$
$$u-k\ln u+\sum_{i=2}^k \frac{(-1)^i}{1-i}\binom ki u^{1-i}+C=$$
$$1+\lambda t-k\ln(1+\lambda t)+\sum_{i=2}^k \frac{(-1)^i}{1-i}\binom ki(1+\lambda t)^{1-i}+C$$